# Which battle won by Judah or the United Kingdom of Israel that was won miraculously had the greatest number of enemy casualties?

Tags: miracles, israel, war

Lots of battles were fought in the Bible. Some were won primarily by a miraculous act of God, such as the fall of Jericho in the days of Joshua or the defeat of Sennacherib's Assyrian army in the days of Hezekiah. The non-miraculous victory with the most enemy casualties that I know of is the Battle of Mount Zemaraim, won by Rehoboam of Judah against the Kingdom of Israel. The Bible claims 500,000 casualties.

Which battle won primarily by a miraculous act of God, fought by either the tribes (Moses through Samuel), United Kingdom (Saul to Solomon) or the Kingdom of Judah (Rehoboam to the Exile)...

- claimed the most enemy casualties?
- was fought against the largest opposing army?

I am looking for battles prior to the Babylonian Exile, ca 585 BC.

The greatest victory I know of is the defeat of Sennacherib, with 185,000 enemy casualties:

> 32 “Therefore thus says the Lord concerning the king of Assyria: He
> shall not come into this city or shoot an arrow there, or come before
> it with a shield or cast up a siege mound against it. 33 By the way
> that he came, by the same he shall return, and he shall not come into
> this city, declares the Lord. 34 For I will defend this city to save
> it, for my own sake and for the sake of my servant David.”  35 And
> that night the angel of the Lord went out and **struck down 185,000 in
> the camp of the Assyrians**. And when people arose early in the morning,
> behold, these were all dead bodies. 36 Then Sennacherib king of
> Assyria departed and went home and lived at Nineveh. 37 And as he was
> worshiping in the house of Nisroch his god, Adrammelech and Sharezer,
> his sons, struck him down with the sword and escaped into the land of
> Ararat. And Esarhaddon his son reigned in his place. (2 Ki 19:32–37)

Is there a greater miraculous victory that I overlooked?

Comment: Some might say victory in the European theater of WWII was at least remarkable if not miraculous, and there was a time the UK stood alone against Hitler. Oh, you mean THAT united kingdom. Had me confused for a minute --!

Comment: Population growth globally over the past two thousand years makes any comparison meaningless, I would suggest.

Comment: Are you asking for battles miraculously won prior to 931 B.C. approx?

Comment: @Lesley - Battles recorded in the Old Testament, up to the time of the Exile, or roughly 585 BC. (There are no battles in the NT except in prophecies.)

Comment: Would this link about the various kings of the United Kingdom and then the Divided Kingdom be useful?   https://www.gotquestions.org/kings-Israel-Judah.html

Comment: Minor point - acc to 2 Chronicles 13:4, the Battle of Zemaraim involved King Abijah of Judah not Rehoboam. Major point... it WAS described as miraculously won... see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry to disagree with the OP's premise but the Bible indeed describes the [Battle of Mount Zemaraim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Mount_Zemaraim) as a miraculous victory for Judah. Unfortunately the enemy in this case was Israel. Judah's army was outnumbered 2-1 in terms of troops and the enemy king had trapped Judah's army in a ambush, effectively surrounding it.

2 Chronicles 13 then describes God's miraculous intervention in response to Judah's prayers and priestly trumpet calls:

> Jeroboam (of Israel) had sent an ambush around to come on them from
> behind; thus his troops were in front of Judah, and the ambush was
> behind them. 14 When Judah turned, the battle was in front of them and
> behind them. *They cried out to the Lord, and the priests blew the
> trumpets. 15 Then the people of Judah raised the battle shout. And
> when the people of Judah shouted, God defeated Jeroboam and all Israel
> before Abijah and Judah.* 16 The Israelites fled before Judah, and God
> gave them into their hands. 17 Abijah and his army defeated them with
> great slaughter; **five hundred thousand picked men of Israel fell
> slain.**

**Biblical numbers of soldiers and casualties are highly controversial, and may be taken with a grain of salt. However, the answer to the OP's question is the Battle of Mount Zemaraim.  God's decisive response to prayer in the midst of a hopeless military situation is definitely miraculous.**

Comment: No need to be sorry. I was exhausted when I posted the question and overlooked that important detail.